# JQuery Datatables display hidden values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

Here's what I want to accomplish: Using datatables I want to display some infromation extracted from a database, after that, using DataTables hidden row details I want to display the rest of the information. The first part is done and working perfectly, however I haven't had any success with the second part.

Here's the php code that returns the json code (which I believe is working just fine):

```
<?php

        try {
            $conn = require_once 'dbConnect.php';

            $sql = "SELECT email, lastName, firstName, dateRegistered, state FROM Users";

            $result = $conn->prepare($sql) or die ($sql);

            if(!$result->execute()) return false;

            if($result->rowCount() > 0) {
                $json = array();
                while($row = $result->fetch()){
                    $json[] = array(
                        'email' => $row['email'],
                        'lastName' => $row['lastName'],
                        'firstName' => $row['firstName'],
                        'dateRegistered' => $row['dateRegistered'],
                        'state' => $row['state']
                    );
                }

                $response = array(
                    "iTotalRecords" => strval(count($json)),
                    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => strval(count($json)),
                    "aaData" => $json
                );

                echo json_encode($response);

            }
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

?>
```

In my datatable I want to display all the info but the state, which will be hidden.

```
/*
 * Created by: Sebastian Bonilla
 * Date: 12-12-2013
 * Version: 0.9
 */


/* Formating function for row details */
function fnFormatDetails ( oTable, nTr )
{
    // Creates the details block
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );
    var sOut = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">';
// I tried to access states with aData[5] but it didn't work. With any value it says 'undefined'
    sOut += '<tr><td>State:</td><td>' + aData[5] + '</td></tr>';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Link to source:</td><td>Could provide a link here</td></tr>';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Extra info:</td><td>And any further details here (images etc)</td></tr>';
    sOut += '</table>';

    // return a html formatted string with the data to display
    return sOut;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    /*
    $('#datatables').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": 'process.php'
    } );
    */

    // Create object oTable which is a datatable
    // makes an ajax call to process.php and populate the headers
    var oTable = $('#datatables').dataTable( {
        "aaSorting": [[2, 'asc']],
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sAjaxSource": "process.php",
        "aoColumns": [
            {
                "mData": null,
                "aTargets": [0],
                "bSerchable": false,
                "bSortable": false,
                "sDefaultContent": '<div class="expand /">',
                "sWidth": "30px"
            },
            { 
                "mDataProp": "email",
                "aTargets": [1],
                "bSearchable": true,
                "bSortable": true
            },
            { 
                "mDataProp": "lastName",
                "aTargets": [2],
                "bSearchable": true,
                "bSortable": true
            },
            { 
                "mDataProp": "firstName",
                "aTargets": [3],
                "bSearchable": true,
                "bSortable": true
            },
            { 
                "mDataProp": "dateRegistered",
                "aTargets": [4],
                "sClass": "center",
                "bSearchable": true,
                "bSortable": true
            }
        ]
    } );


    $('#datatables tbody').on('click', 'td div.expand', function () {
    var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
    if (oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr)) {
        $(this).removeClass('open');
        oTable.fnClose(nTr);
    } else {$.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode = 'throw' ;
        $(this).addClass('open');
        oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details');
    }
});

});
```

So, as I said, I'm able to display all the values that I want, but when in the fnFormatDetails function I'm not able to access and display states.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I was just able to figure it out!

Here's how it works: Instead of accessing the field with an index like aData[5] do it with the field's name: aData['state'] and done.